# How to get the base class offset of an inherited struct without creating an instance

Tags: c++, class, virtual-table

Consider this code:

```
struct A {
    int64 member;
    int32 member2;
    virtual void f();
};

struct B {
    int16 member3;

    virtual void b();
};

struct C : A, B {
    virtual void b() override;
};
```

I'm interested in finding the offset of `B` in `C`. Previously with other structs with no virtual inheritance and only one base class `offsetof` of the first member seemed to work. I have decompiled some code (in IDA) and the base classes are nicely highlighted  (hex) here:

[image: screenshot]

In a function those exact baseclass offsets are used to cast `void*`'s to derived classes by adding the offset to the `void*` (by casting to a `char*`). The structs `A`, `B` and `C` are similar to the one in the compiled code, which include classes with virtual functions and multiple base classes.

My question is how did they do that, and how can I do that? I've tried something like `i32 offset = (i64)((B*)((C*)NULL));` but no luck.

Comment: "virtual base classes" isn't occuring here. you have bases with virtual members, not virtual bases. If you had virtual bases the answer would be "there is no unique answer"

Comment: Who are "they", and did they have access to the debug symbols for this program?

Comment: your right, meant virtual member functions. Its a game engine, and yes since I have the PDB if thats what you mean. The code to find the offsets would have been compile time generated since I can see the raw offsets in the data segment of the executable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried the following, and it worked:

```
(char*)(B*)(C*)0x100 - (char*)(C*)0x100
```

It casts `C*` to `B*`; this is supposed to do the work. All the rest is support. I used an arbitrary number `0x100`; it seems to work with all numbers except 0.

Why it doesn't work for 0: it sees a null-pointer of type `C*`; to convert it to a null-pointer of type `B*`, it should still be null. A special case.

Of course, this uses undefined behavior. It seems to work in Visual Studio in my short test program; no guarantee it will work anywhere else.

Comment: Perfect, works! Thanks a lot, frustrating that it was just because it was null, but I see since the compiler would try to optimize that since it sees its a constant of null

Comment: It's not because of the optimization. It'd horrific if casting a null pointer would give us a non-null pointer. Then it'd be impossible to handle invalid pointers after a cast.

Comment: Trying this with Visual Studio 2019 gets me error `Access of field '$cast' not supported`

Comment: @Jonathan You might want to ask a question about that. Use the "Ask Question" link. Might be interesting for some people, including myself.

Comment: @anatolyg https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76892949